# Can I have an electric dryer, a washer, furnace, and gas water heater all in one laundry room?

Tags: hvac, water, dryer, washing-machine, heater

Can I have an electric dryer, a washer, furnace, and gas water heater all in one laundry room?

Basically, my electric dryer is on the far outside wall. Almost literally against it, the dryer vent thing on the back goes to a vent on the wall that's literally right there where the dryer is. Pretty close.

Next to the dryer is my washing machine. Then next to the washing machine is my gas water heater. After that, is my furnace.

Is there any issue with this sort of set up? They're all basically side by side, none of them touching each other or anything like that. There's a decent amount of space between them. They're just all in a row down the same wall.

Comment: The dryer, furnace, and water heater all need to breathe. Each of those appliances draws air from the room it's in and pumps it outside. You have to  make sure that the room is vented well enough so that the three appliances can all run at the same time.

Comment: If you're looking for online resources on the matter, the room is often referred to as a mechanical closet (Though these often excludes the laundry appliances). . . +1 to @A.I.Breveleri , there is nothing inherently wrong with the setup so long as everything is properly vented.

Comment: @A.I.Breveleri   That's an answer. Type it up as one, I'll upvote.

Comment: Are your water heater and furnace atmospheric vented (with no air inlet pipe coming in and a traditional flue pipe going out), or sealed-combustion (with an air inlet pipe going in and a similar pipe going out)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Only issue I can see is where the makeup air comes from. The washer doesn't matter, but if the dryer, furnace, and water heater all turn on at the same time, they each need air input. Putting everything in one room can cause an issue where it's easier to suck air through the output of another appliance than suck air from inside the house, and that can leave carbon monoxide inside the house.

The input air can come from inside the house (in which case there should be some sort of vent in the door or something), or outside (in which case you should be able to see the vent.)

I would also highly suggest installing a carbon monoxide alarm somewhere in the home if not already present, and testing it if it exists already. This is general advice whenever gas appliances are in use.